# How do I get flex container divs to be 100 percent in width on resize of the browser?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Is it possible to get the divs in a felx-container (display:flex) to be 100 percent when the screen size reduced to that of a mobile phone (something like at max-width: 480px)?

Let us take this as an example:

````css
.flex-container { background-color: #F4F7F8; resize: horizontal; overflow: hidden; display: flex; margin: 1em; }
.item { margin: 1em; padding: 0.5em; width: 110px; min-width: 0; background-color: #1B5385; color: white; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.four { flex: 4; }
.two { flex: 2; }
.one { flex: 1; }
```
````

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item four">4</div>
    <div class="item two">2</div>
    <div class="item one">1</div>
</div>
```

Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p73vx651/)

On shrinking the screen size from a desktop/laptop to that of a mobile phone I would want it to be something like

[image: a busy cat]

I did this by adding

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.flex-container { display:block; }
.item { width: 100%; }
}
```

to the css file.

I do not know if this the right way of getting it done or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using flex, the proper way to achieve this is by applying `flex-direction: column` to `flex-container`. In that case flex items will be reorganized to form columns instead of rows (as on bigger screens):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .flex-container { flex-direction: column; }
  .item { width: 100%; }
}
```

[flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_main_axis)

Answer (score 1):

change the flex container direction type to column. it will help

```
.flex-container { flex-direction: column; }
```